# Finding the minimum of $E = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^m \delta_i^2 t_i^{-1}$ using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\delta_i,t_i > 0$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ for $i=1,\dots,m$. I read that the minimum of the following (error) quantity can be found using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
$$
E = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^m \delta_i^2 t_i^{-1}.
$$
The minimum happens at:
$$
t_i = \frac{\delta_i}{\sum_{i=1}^m \delta_j}.
$$
I don't how this was arrived at, does anyone know the method that was used?

Comment: what does "minimum" mean: What is fixed? What is changing?

Comment: By differentiating $E$ wrt $t_i$, you'll arrive at something similar result. But I don't know how to apply Cauchy Schwartz inequality on it, I believe using it gives an upper bound to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : You can apply Cauchy-Schwartz inequality as follow

\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{i=1}^m \delta_i \right) E &=\frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m (\delta_i^{1/2})^2 \right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^m \left(\delta_i t_i^{-1/2}\right)^2\right)\\
&\geq \frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m \delta_i^{3/2} t^{-1/2} \right)
\end{align*}
with equality if and only if $\delta_i^{1/2}=c\delta_i t_i^{-1/2}$ for some $c$ and for all $i$.

To finish the proof, I make the assumption that you optimize subject to $\sum t_i=1$. Using $\delta_i^{1/2}=c\delta_i t_i^{-1/2}$ we see that $t_i=c^2 \delta_i$ which means that $c^2 \sum \delta_i = 1$ and so $c^2=\frac{1}{\sum \delta_i}$. Finally $t_i=\frac{\delta_i}{\sum_j \delta_j}$

Comment: Isn't it $\geq$ in the second line of your answer? I referred the inequality from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: @NarendraDeconda yes of course, and the point is to find a minimum on $E$ and see when it is achieved, not a maximum, so we give a lower bound on it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you prove how $c^2=\sum_{i=1}^{m} \delta_j$?

Comment: @NarendraDeconda yes, see my edit. Note that if we don't have constraint on $t_i$, there is no minimum, only an infimum that is $E=0$

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice thanks!